# Visual Composer admin-ajax.php loading time issue

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocomerce and I have add to cart button with ajax. The problem is that if Visual Composer is not activated, I get a reply from admin-ajax.php of less than 2 seconds. When I activate Visual Composer the reply comes in about 7 seconds.

Is there a way to deactivate all the Visual Composer functions that admin-ajax.php is using on certain pages like product pages, where I am adding to cart with ajax?

Comment: Not a specific answer, but I had nothing but problems with Visual Composer and have happily switched to [Beaver Builder](https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know there are issues with Visual Composer but the website is already developed and my only problem is the ajax loading time. There's too much functionality developed and it's very difficult to change it now.

Comment: Understandable. I just got tired of falling into the rabbit hole of these types of problems caused by poor coding. But, maybe [heartbeat control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/) or [ajax heartbeat tool](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-heartbeat-tool/) can help.

Comment: So how did you solve that? If you ...